# Style JSF datatable with primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces

How can I style my datatable with CSS? I tried a lot of solutions, but nothing works. I tried the one in primefaces official website and primefaces user guide, but neither of them work.

Here's the code I have:

```
<p:dataTable var="car" value="#{carListController.cars}">
   <p:column filterBy=”#{car.model}”>
      <f:facet name="header"> 
          <h:outputText value="Model" />
      </f:facet>
      <h:outputText value="#{car.model}" />
   </p:column>
   ...more columns 
</p:dataTable>
```

If anyone can help me out here, I would very much appreciate it.

Comment: Style which part of datatable?

Comment: @Cagatay Civici Header and rows( change the color of the rows for exemple : white, blue, white, blue...)

Comment: @Optimmus, you need to be more specific and show us what you have tried to do.

Comment: @Cagatay Civici first i want to thank you for your reply...

Comment: @Cagatay Civici This is the code i try to do:

i added a new datatable with this code but the filter output area don't show :

<p:dataTable var="car" value="#{carListController.cars}">
<p:column filterBy=”#{car.model}”>
<f:facet name="header">
<h:outputText value="Model" />
</f:facet>
<h:outputText value="#{car.model}" />
</p:column>
...more columns
</p:dataTable>

Comment: @Cagatay Civici i tryed to change the skin with this CSS code but don't work too :
.yui-skin-sam .yui-dt table {
border-color: #99FF00;
}
.yui-skin-sam .yui-dt th {
background: url(../design/nav.gif);
border: none;
}
.yui-skin-sam tr.yui-dt-odd {
background: #FFFFCC;
}
.yui-skin-sam tr.yui-dt-even {
background: #FFFFFF;
}
.yui-skin-sam .yui-dt td {
border-color: #FFFFFF;
}
.yui-skin-sam .yui-dt-paginator a.yui-pg-last,
.yui-skin-sam .yui-dt-paginator a.yui-pg-first,
.yui-skin-sam .yui-dt-paginator a.yui-pg-next,
.yui-skin-sam .yui-dt-paginator a.yui-pg-previous {
color: #33CC00;
}

Answer (score 3):

I think there are many ways to color a datatable with CSS. For me it worked by displaying a list where each item also has an ID, so i used:

```
<p:dataTable id="xyzDataTable" var="data" value="#{myBean.data}" 
    selectionMode="single" rowStyleClass="#{data.id mod 2 == 0 ? null : 'old'}">
```

the CSS File

```
.old
{
  background:#fafafa;
}
```

now every second row has a different color.

Comment: i didn't understand this id="xyzDataTable" and data.id

Comment: xyzDataTable is simple a random id for the p:dataTable and data.id is the ID column of my data source because i use a data source which is numbered so i only set every even number (every second line) with another background color.

Comment: @Optimmus ,@Cagatay Civici Is possible to compare two dates like `rowStyleClass="#{bean.date1 lt currentDate ?'red':'blue'}"`

Answer (score 0):

another solution: you can use JavaScript. For my DataTable i wanted to color the column and the line of the element which has the focus. The DataTable contains many inputText elements, each of them calls that JavaScript Function if it gets the focus:

```
<p:inputText id="xyz" ... onfocus="colorTR(#{data.id},1);" .../>
```

with the JavaScript Function:

```
//colors row
function colorTR(row, cell){
  var x = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');
  var count = x.length;
  for(var i=0; i!=count; ++i){
    if(x[i].id[0] == 'p'){
      if(i%2 == 0)
        x[i].style.background = '#eeeeee';
      else
        x[i].style.background = '#fafafa';

      var zahl = parseInt(x[i].id[x[i].id.length-2] + x[i].id[x[i].id.length-1]);
      if(isNaN(zahl))
        zahl = parseInt(x[i].id[x[i].id.length-1]);
      if(zahl == row)
        x[i].style.background = '#feac5b';
      }
  }

  //colors column
  x = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
  count = x.length;
  for(var i=0; i!=count; ++i){
    if(x[i].id[0] == 'p'){
      x[i].parentNode.style.background = 'transparent';

      var zahl = parseInt(x[i].id[x[i].id.length-2] + x[i].id[x[i].id.length-1]);
      if(isNaN(zahl))
         zahl = parseInt(x[i].id[x[i].id.length-1]);
      if(zahl == cell)
         x[i].parentNode.style.background = '#feac5b';
    }
  }

  //header column
  x = document.getElementsByTagName('th');
  count = x.length;
  for(var i=0; i!=count; ++i){
    if(x[i].id[0] == 'p'){
      x[i].style.background = '#ffffff';

      var zahl = parseInt(x[i].id[x[i].id.length-2] + x[i].id[x[i].id.length-1]);
      if(isNaN(zahl))
        zahl = parseInt(x[i].id[x[i].id.length-1]);
      if(i == cell)
        x[i].style.background = '#feac5b';
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use rowStyleClass of primefaces in the datatable for example
        "#{o.netWt le 1980 ? 'existing' : null}"
here it means that i have choosen any one the columns in the datatable for checking whether it meets certain condition, if it doesnt i am showing the existing class CSS otherwise null. 
where existing is a CSS Class  like
        .existing {
         background-color:  #0E8C3A !important; 
          background-image: none !important; 
          color: #E0EEEE !important;
                      }

Answer (score 0):

I think you already tried to assign a class name to your components and link a local CSS sheet  right? that should be working.